# AS3 Bouncing Ball

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay, after learning tutorials online, I'm trying to make a bouncing ball in AS3.

Here's my code thus far:

```
var count:Number = 0;
var bounceHeight:Number = 100;
var floorHeight:Number = 300;
var speed:Number = .1;

function run(e:Event):void
{
ball_mc.y = floorHeight - Math.abs(Math.cos(count)) * bounceHeight;
count += speed;
}

{
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME(run));
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

**EDIT:** The compiler errors are

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 13    1195: Attempted access of
> inaccessible method ENTER_FRAME through a reference with static type
> Class.
>
> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 13    1136: Incorrect
> number of arguments.  Expected 2.

Answer (score 1):

Within your closure, `addEventListener` requires a type parameter and a listener function.

Your type is `Event.ENTER_FRAME` and your handler is `run`, which means to call `run` every frame you need:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, run);
```

Therefore, your code should be:

```
function run(e:Event):void
{
    ball_mc.y = floorHeight - Math.abs(Math.cos(count)) * bounceHeight;
    count += speed;
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, run);
```